# Swift - show a complex View in UITableViewController with empty list through Storyboard

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, empty-list

I'd need to show a View with some UIImageView, texts and links in my TableViewController if list controller is empty.

I know you can insert a label through this code:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    var numOfSections: Int = 0
    if youHaveData
    {
        tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        numOfSections            = 1
        tableView.backgroundView = nil
    }
    else
    {
        let noDataLabel: UILabel     = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))
        noDataLabel.text          = "No data available"
        noDataLabel.textColor     = UIColor.black
        noDataLabel.textAlignment = .center
        tableView.backgroundView  = noDataLabel
        tableView.separatorStyle  = .none
    }
    return numOfSections
}
```

But I'd need to show a complex View designed in the Storyboard in a different ViewController.

I tried with this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let emptyViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"empty_controller") as! EmptyViewController
tableView.backgroundView  = emptyViewController.emptyView
```

Where emptyView is defined in this way

```
class EmptyViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var emptyView: UIView?

  ...
}
```

But it doesn't work, I can't see that view in the table if the list is empty.

How can I do it?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to use two containers view one with tableview and one with emptyVC, then in parent of that container you can hide/unhide or remove/add view depending upon your logic

Comment: yes, but I'd like to have a different controller where insert UI Components

Comment: With Container Controller you can have to different controller embedded in Parent Controller

Answer (score 0):

`EmptyViewController` has its own `view`, why you have to create another `emptyView`?

Remote `emptyView` property and use this code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let emptyViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"empty_controller") as! EmptyViewController
tableView.backgroundView  = emptyViewController.view
```

Answer (score 0):

Set you view controller to inherit from UITableViewDelegate and set the tableView.delegate to point to your VC.

```
class VC : UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Then override the following two functions

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

}
```

This'll add a header to your tableview section. You can edit what this header is based on the contents of the table